# Populating tel attribute in JQM

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Please how can I get this piece of code to call the number that is stored in id = "bookTel" which is retrieved from a database?

```
<a href="tel:<???>"data-role="button"> Call <span id="bookTel"></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a id="telephoneNum" href="tel:<???>"data-role="button"> Call <span id="bookTel"></span></a>

$(document).ready(function(){
   var num= $('#bookTel').text();
   $('#telephoneNum').attr('href','tel:'+num);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It didnt work. I tried wrapping it into  $(document).bind('pageinit'){

Comment: Thanks. It didnt work. I tried wrapping it into 

 $(document).bind('pageinit'){

because its a JQM app. Its not populating the tel attribute with a number. The button shows 'Call NUMBER RETURNED by id="bookTel" but the call dialog box contains no number. Thanks

Comment: Do you get the `telnum` in the `span id="bookTel"`?